# How to evaluate one point $(x,y,z)$ in one $2$-form in $\mathbb R^3 $?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, tensors

How to evaluate one point $(x,y,z)$ in one $2$-form in $\mathbb R^3 $? For example, I'm trying to evaluate $\omega = \omega_1 dx\wedge dy + \omega_2 dx\wedge dz+\omega_3 dy\wedge dz$. Hence when I will apply one point $(x,y,z)$ then

$$\omega (x,y,z)= \omega_1 (x,y,z) dx\wedge dy + \omega_2 (x,y,z)dx\wedge dz+\omega_3(x,y,z) dy\wedge dz.$$

My question is more theoretical; I need to evaluate too.    $dx(x,y,z)\wedge dy(x,y,z)$,$dx(x,y,z)\wedge dz(x,y,z)$ and $dy(x,y,z)\wedge dz(x,y,z)$? If the answer is yes, what is the result of this? I mean what is $dx(x,y,z)\wedge dy(x,y,z)=?$

Comment: This depends on your definition of a $2$-form in $\mathbb R^3$ (or more general, a $k$-form on $\mathbb R^n$, where $k \leq n$).

Comment: im reading the Spivak's book (calculus on Manifolds) page 88, one k form in $\mathbb R^n$ applicated to $p\in \mathbb R^n$ like $\omega(p)=\sum_{i_1<\ldots<i_k }\omega_{i_1,\ldots,i_k}(p)[\phi_{i_1}(p)\wedge \ldots\wedge\phi_{i_k}(p)]$. i am confuse because i dont now how to evaluate  this

Comment: well azifmedrano thank you for you comment, just im very confuse, i think $[\phi_{i_1}(p)\wedge \ldots\wedge\phi_{i_k}(p)]$ is a basis so this never can be evaluate, but what happen when i change of point, i know that every $\phi_i$ is a dual basis of $e_i$ where $e_i$ is standar basis for $\mathbb R^3$,

Comment: I just added an answer. Hope it clarifies the definitions a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $p \in \mathbb R^3$. Then the tangent space of $\mathbb R^3$ at $p$, denoted by $\mathbb R^3_p$, is the set of all vectors of the form $v_p := (p,v)$, where $v \in \mathbb R^3$, with addition and scalar multiplication given by $$av_p+w_p := (av+w)_p$$
where $v,w \in \mathbb R^3$ and $a \in \mathbb R$.

Now, if $e_1,e_2,e_3$ is the standard basis for $\mathbb R^3$, $(e_1)_p,(e_2)_p,(e_3)_p$ is a basis for $\mathbb R^3_p$, and then we denote its dual basis by $dx(p),dy(p),dz(p)$.
That is, $dx(p),dy(p),dz(p)$ are the unique linear functions from $\mathbb R^3_p$ to $\mathbb R$ such that each $v_p \in \mathbb R^3_p$ can be written as
$$v_p = dx(p)(v_p)(e_1)_p + dy(p)(v_p)(e_2)_p + dz(p)(v_p)(e_3)_p.$$

Next, we define $(dx \wedge dy)(p)$ by $dx(p) \wedge dy(p)$, which is now an alternating bilinear function $\mathbb R^3_p \times \mathbb R^3_p \to \mathbb R$. Similarly, we define $(dx \wedge dz)(p)$ and $(dy \wedge dz)(p)$.

Finally, the $2$-form
$$\omega = f_1 dx \wedge dy + f_2dx \wedge dz + f_3dy \wedge dz$$
on $\mathbb R^3$, is the function such that for each $p \in \mathbb R^3$,
$$\omega(p) = f_1(p)(dx \wedge dy)(p) + f_2(p)(dx \wedge dz)(p) + f_3(p)(dy \wedge dz)(p).$$

Comment: thank you so much